# Using rlang::sym inside list definition

Tags: r, tidyr, rlang, quasiquotes

I'm writing an R script and I need to allow user to specify the name of variable that will be proccessed by hand, i.e.

```
var <- 'user_name'
```

Generally then I refer to that using `rlang::sym` and quoting/unquoting mechanism. However, I need to use `tidyr::replace_na` and none of my ideas worked here as the name of the variable has to be specified inside `list`.

How can I refer to my `var` in such a case? I was thinking about something like below:

```
data <- data %>% replace_na(list(sym(var) = 0))
```

But it didn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can also put `replace_na` inside `mutate` and unquote:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

var <- 'user_name'

data %>%
  mutate(!!var := replace_na(!!sym(var), 0))
```

**Result:**

```
  user_name
1         0
2         1
3         2
4         3
5         4
6         5
```

**Data:**

```
data <- data.frame(user_name = c(NA, 1:5))
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using any external packages other than `dplyr/tidyr`, we can change this with `setNames`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
    replace_na(as.list(setNames(0, var)))
#   user_name
#1         0
#2         3
#3         4
```

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(user_name = c(NA, 3, 4))
```